# Timeout parent activity after a given interval

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity, startactivityforresult

I have a child activity.  I then call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);
startActivity(intent);
```

If the user doesn't do anything for 60 seconds, I want to return to the child activity to do something else.  However once I call `startActivity(intent);` or even `startActivityForResult(intent);` I can't figure out how to get back to the child activity.

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean by the child activity?

Comment: @AhmedHegazy I have an activity that the user is in initially (child).  From there we call Intent intent = new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);